# Best performance in filtering large datasets: = ANY() or @> on an array column; XOR on a bitmapped binary column; join a m2m table or something else?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, database-performance

**The General Question:**

This question pertains to tables with a large number of rows (say millions) that has a many to many relationship with a relatively small set of data (say tens).  For example you might have 20 different tags or types or categories and each of your 10 million records is associated with one or more of them.

- You could have a separate table for your tags with 20 rows and then use a many to many table to define the relationships between those 20 tags and your 10 million records.
- In Postgres there are array types that could be used instead. In mySQL there is a the SET column type that like that.
- You could also use a bitmap or bit string type and perform an XOR on that column.

My question is which of these solutions (or an alternative solution) is best for performance when querying the large table for records that are associated with one member of the small set.  A solution should include what indexes to create and use.

**My Specifics:**

I've tried to keep the question here as generic as possible because I believe the answer could be applicable in many fairly common scenarios.  However, for clarity I'll describe my specific situation now.

I have a table with millions of titles.  Each title is associated with one or more languages.  For example 'Don Quixote' may be 'Дон Кихот' in Russian, Bulgarian, Kazakh and 'Don Quijote' in a bunch of other languages.  I have a search string and a language and want to find the best match in titles.  I'm using Postgres and have a trigram index using gin on the titles.  An example search would be find matches for 'Дон Кихот' in Bulgarian.

Currently have have the languages in a char(2)[] array type column using two letter language codes.  I assume using an int array with language IDs would be better, but I want to go for what is best.  I'm not worried about how much effort it would take to setup a bitmap for languages to do an XOR search or whatever effort and complexity is involved in implementing a particular solution.  The performance is what matters.

I would tend to think that JOINing a many to many table would not be the best solution because that table would have multiple entries per row in the title table and so it would be huge.  But perhaps I'm wrong about that because that is what RDBMS are designed to do.

Huge thanks to all of you who spend your highly valuable time answering these questions.

Answer (score 1):

The postgreSQL documentation warns against [searching arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING).

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

SQL in general, and postgreSQL in particular, is astonishingly good at joining vast many-to-many tables, especially when their rows are modestly sized, their columns' data types match the columns you use for joining, and they have the right indexes.

So avoid arrays for the application you describe.

For a two-column junction table like you describe, you'd define it as something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE title_lang (
    title_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    lang_id SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (title_id, lang_id)
};

CREATE INDEX lang_title ON title_lang (lang_id, title_id);
```

I used `SMALLINT` for the language id. When you use character types, the database gives you unicode characters. Those take unexpected amounts of space. And indexes on integers are very efficient. But you should use the data type that makes sense in the rest of your schema.

I suggest a primary key going from title to language, and a reverse key going the other way. You can omit the reverse key if you don't go from language to title.

To associate a title with a language you insert a row in the table. To get rid of the association you delete the row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So as a m2m table it would only have 2 columns. I could use numeric(2,0) for the language id to keep the rows sized as modestly as possible.  The title id is integer (over 100 million rows).  Can you expound on what the right indexes would be.  Obviously the title id would be the pkey of the title table and foreign  key in the m2m.  Same for the language id and the language table.  Is there anything else you would do to optimize indexes?